# Firebase reference is empty after requiring new version

Tags: node.js, firebase

The new [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#authenticate-with-admin-privileges) provides a straightforward method of initialising firebase, for example, this snipped comes directly from the `README.md` file:

> Install the Firebase npm module:
>
> `$ npm init`
>   `$ npm install --save firebase`
>
> In your code, you can access Firebase using:
>
> `var firebase = require('firebase');`
>   `var app = firebase.intializeApp({ ... });`
>   `// ...`

But in my installation this is not working, as in, `firebase` is empty (`{}` when console logged).

There's another section in the documentation called **Include only the features you need**, which provides the following snippet:

```
var firebase = require('firebase/app');
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/database');

var app = firebase.initializeApp({ ... });
// ...
```

This method works for me, so I'm wondering what could I be doing wrong in the first instance?

<sub>I'm using `browserify`, if that helps, but the docs state: The browser version is designed to be used with
a package bundler (e.g., [Browserify](http://browserify.org/),
[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)).</sub>