# firebase.initializeApp is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to make a site in React, and I have added the Firebase library using `npm i firebase --save`

I am then trying to call this in my app, but I am not having much joy:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";

const instance = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '123',
  authDomain: 'https://123.firebaseapp.com/',
  databaseURL: 'https://123.firebaseio.com/'
});

export default instance;
```

No matter what I try, it throws:

> firebase.initializeApp is not a function

I've checked its in my node_modules and i've reinstalled it, but I still have no such luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: David East has a great video on firebase and react. Check it out . From his video he only initializes firebase from the main file in the project and doesnt export it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwNATxfUsgI. Theres the link. Hope this helps

Comment: That's not the issue, i've tried that and i still cant get it to work

Comment: Could you try - just for debugging purposes - to require firebase like this: `const firebase = require('firebase')`. Also, which version of firebase did you use?

Comment: That still throws the same error.  I am using just firebase (web) on 3.6.8

Comment: I've updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: I have this error also using firebase 7.14.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you please try with:

`var firebase = require('firebase/app');`

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37338380/4312466).

Answer (score 20):

I had a the same problem with firestore in my Vue application.

I eventually came right by doing the following in my firebase.js file:

```
import { firebase } from '@firebase/app'
```

As opposed to :

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
```

Also if you are using any specific firebase modules you need to import them individually like so:

```
import '@firebase/auth'
import '@firebase/firestore'

const db = firebase.firestore()
const auth = firebase.auth()

export { db, auth }
```

Hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me why/how this works? Why does firebase even expose a scoped `@firebase/app` package? Why both a scoped `@firebase` and regular `firebase` directory in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 13):

This is how I solved this

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "Api Key",
  authDomain: "Domain",
  databaseURL: "URL",
  projectId: "ID",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
export default db;
```

Answer (score 3):

Been having a similar issue with `firebase v4.12.1` throwing error of `initializeApp` not being a function. I solved it by switching to using `@firebase/app 0.1.10` npm package instead.

`import { firebase } from '@firebase/app';`

Using it in a next.js `v5.1.0` project.

Comment: Quite right, @andykenward, my mistake! I would have edited the comment but SO doesn't support that, so deleting and leaving this comment to give you props instead. (I had seen that the "updated by..." on NPM was a personal account and not a Google-looking account and missed that that was an official contributor and wrongly expressed concern that this package was 3rd party.)

Comment: Thanks! Seems similar to the answer above. Can you tell me why/how this works? Why does firebase even expose a scoped @firebase/app package? Why both a scoped @firebase and regular firebase directory in node_modules

Answer (score 3):

been having the same problem but in VUE, in case it works i solved importing each element separately

```
// This import loads the firebase namespace.
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

// These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';
```

Hope can help ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is the new firebase SKD modular  recommendation. Avoid using the

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

and try to use modular import, such as:

```
import {initializeApp} from "firebase/app";
const instance = {
  apiKey: '123',
  authDomain: 'https://123.firebaseapp.com/',
  databaseURL: 'https://123.firebaseio.com/'
};

export const app = initializeApp(instance);
```

references
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#modular-version

Answer (score 0):

```js
const auth = firebase.auth()

export { db, auth }`import * as firebase from "firebase";
require("@firebase/firestore");

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export default firebase.firestore();
```